# Bootstrap column alignment in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple columns in a single div without row. I achieved to move the column down if its has title . But next div can't comes automatically to right side.

```
  <div class="secn-frst1">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <h3>no title</h3>
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <h3>have title</h3>
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <h3>no title</h3>
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <h3>no title</h3>
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        //have title
    </div>
</div>
<div class="secn-frst2">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <h3>no title</h3>
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <h3>have title</h3>
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <h3>no title</h3>
        //content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        //have title
    </div>
</div>
```

I applied `display:block` and `clear:both` for `col-xs-6` to move down if it has title (for 2nd column) but the 3rd column not coming to right side like left and right. I need to do this without `row` because of all column should randomly appears to left and right.

[Here my site](http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/product/view/Homogeneous)

[screen for ref](https://prnt.sc/iu2ubj)

Comment: Add a seperate class if the div has a title then apply your css on that class

Comment: can you explain with any sample code?

Comment: your are using bootstrap 4?

Comment: No. bootstrap 3

Comment: @John I have added an answer, please check whether it is meeting your requirement

Comment: @John any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Divide each sections with titles with a container-fuild and add a row.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional Bootstrap theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="secn-frst1">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
      <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-12744.png">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>have title</h3>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-12744.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-12744.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-12744.png">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>have title</h3>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-12744.png">
  </div>

</div>

<hr>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="secn-frst2">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
      <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-12744.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>have title</h3>

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-12744.png"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-12744.png"> </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>have title</h3>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://mobilegear.my/alphatiles/assets_user/product/alpha_2018-01-12744.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Guna Main thing need to do without row. As I previously mentioned in my question

Comment: @John removed the row class from the code, still it works though. Updated the snippet

Comment: `<div class="container-fluid">` remove the container . only one div must be appear above the `col-xs6`. check my site in mobile view